# Limitations in mechanical font design and typesetting

Tags: fonts

This may be slightly off-topic; but I hope it will pass.

What limitations of mechanical font design and typesetting do not exist in TeX
and METAFONT?  In particular, did mechanical types tend to have
a rather limited set of possible glyph widths?  And --in
practice-- limited possibilities of kerning?  How was spacing
inserted?  Has any attempt been made to imitate such limitations
in digital font design and typesetting?

Answer (score 2):

The most common technology in use for mathematical typesetting when DEK developed TeX was [Monotype’s four-line system.](http://ultrasparky.org/school/pdf/Rhatigan_Monotype_4-line_math.pdf) developed in the late 1950s  This placed some restrictions on character widths: specifically, the widest character in any font had its width divided by 18, the width of every other gylph in the font was a multiple between 3 and 18 of this unit, and glyphs were set in a matrix with the wider characters on the top row.  The major restriction was on the *height* of a glyph.  In the four-line system, a full-sized character would take up two lines, so a fraction with a numerator and denominator might use all four, and superiors or inferiors would typically use one.

Equations still needed to be typeset on their own, and galley lines laid onto plates by hand to paginate them, but this system allowed an operator to automate much of the process on a keyboard, before setting the proofs in hot lead.

Many math fonts today, including STIX, base their appearance on the Times Series 569 font used by the Monotype 4-line system, since that was what the textbooks a generation of mathematicians remember looked like.  Even when hot-metal printing gave way to phototypesetting, the font stayed popular.

DEK, however, chafed at the limitations this imposed on his books, and consciously chose to revive the style of an earlier system developed at Oxford University Press in 1928.  This used the Monotype Modern series no.7 type, since the university was already using it to print dictionaries, which included Greek letters.  (Mathematical texts of that era typically used Porson as their Greek font.)  Prior to that, there had been some promising experiments, but mathematics could only be typeset by hand, and typically you would see things like an uneven baseline.

The way equations were typeset separately is still reflected in how display math leaves a vertical space between paragraphs that it sticks the equation on top of, while text-mode math disables many of the more complicated vertical layouts, such as double-sized sum or integral symbols, limits set above and below, or fractions with full-sized glyphs in the numerator and denominator.  There are still secondary faces of scripts and script-scripts approximately half the size, and large operators are still approximately twice as tall as capital letters.  By default, lowercase Greek letters are still slanted, but capital Greek letters are upright and Latin capitals such as A and B are substituted for similar Greek ones such as Α and Β, a convention originally established back when few printers had a full Greek alphabet.  It’s also become conventional to use whatever typefaces a shop happened to have lying around as mathematical symbols.  This has happened to Fraktur/Blackletter many times.

There are other limitations that carried over as well.  If you open a PDF generated from LaTeX in the 20th century, there’s a good chance the letters look too thin and spindly.  This is primarily a problem with the rasterizers in GhostScript and the lack of hinting in fonts, but it’s also often been a problem that digitizations of a font originally set in metal type fail to take into account how the ink would spread out onto the paper, so digital fonts would look too thin and pointy on the screen.  You’ll also often find typoes such as `re ect` and `di cult` because the PS or PDF document did not embed ligatures.  It was common enough for fonts not to include all the glyphs theoretically part of the encoding that TeX still does not so much as print a warning by default when it happens.

The mechanical printing press required even larger changes to, for example, Arabic and Persian, which often used to be written more diagonally, with much greater horizontal overlap between characters.  Far from kerning being something that mechanical printing limited, the idea that you lay out glyphs horizontally, with the only exception being to shift a glyph slightly left or right if you needed them to overlap, is a model inherently based on the limitations of a mechanical printing press with movable type.